# LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION - Interpetation

Tags: antlr4

When using PredictionMode::LL_EXACT_AMBIG_DETECTION I get the following error messages:

```
line 186:7 reportAttemptingFullContext d=30, input='ON REPORT HEAD
```

How am I to interpret the d attribute. Does it reference a rule in my grammar and how can I find out which?

According to the code:

```
@Override
public void reportAttemptingFullContext(@NotNull Parser recognizer,
    @NotNull DFA dfa,
    int startIndex, int stopIndex,
    @NotNull ATNConfigSet configs)
{
        recognizer.notifyErrorListeners("reportAttemptingFullContext d=" +
            dfa.decision + ", input='" +
            recognizer.getTokenStream().getText(Interval.of(startIndex, stopIndex)) + "'");
}
```

the attribute d is a decision in DFA. But I have not found out how the use the information back to the rule in the grammar.
Thank for your help.
Kind regards,
Wolfgang Hämmer

Answer (score 1):

The following helper methods can convert a decision number to a rule name. You can create your own error listener implementation based on `DiagnosticErrorListener` and use these methods to include the name of the rule in each message.

If a rule has more than one decision, then you can pass the `-atn` flag to ANTLR when you generate code for your grammar. Once you have the name of the rule, look at the graph produced by `ruleName.dot` (where `ruleName` is the rule), and you'll see a node in the graph labeled `d=decisionNumber` (where `decisionNumber` is the number you're currently seeing). That will point you to the *exact* location where the problem is occurring.

Keep in mind that rule and decision numbers change when you change your grammar, so when you open `ruleName.dot` you'll want to verify the actual decision number each you regenerate the code for your grammar.

```
public static int getDecisionRule(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, int decision) {
    if (recognizer == null || decision < 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (decision >= recognizer.getATN().decisionToState.size()) {
        return -1;
    }

    return recognizer.getATN().decisionToState.get(decision).ruleIndex;
}

public static String getRuleDisplayName(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, int ruleIndex) {
    if (recognizer == null || ruleIndex < 0) {
        return Integer.toString(ruleIndex);
    }

    String[] ruleNames = recognizer.getRuleNames();
    if (ruleIndex < 0 || ruleIndex >= ruleNames.length) {
        return Integer.toString(ruleIndex);
    }

    return ruleNames[ruleIndex];
}
```

Comment: Hi Sam,
THIS IS SO COOL!
Thank you very much for your help!

Greetings, wolf